# Bootstrap - Change direction of the navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left, direction

I've using Twitter bootstrap and trying to align the navbars' text to the right, i.e - that the "brand" will appear on the right, and all else to the left of it. (For right-to-left website).

Any ideas how this can be accomplished?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Apply `float:right` to div with class as `navbar-inner`

```
<div class="navbar-inner" style="float:right">
```

Like

```
<div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">    
        <div style="float:right">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
        <ul class="nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9LFV5/10/)

Comment: Just for future reference - After this edit, the order of the items should be reversed (such as the ".brand" should be the last in the div now)

Comment: @roman: If you want to update the order just update the order in `<li>` accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

pull-right and pull-left are default bootstrap classes that can help you achieve that without having to write your own css.
For example,

```
    <div class="navbar pull-right"></div> [equivalent to float:right]
    <div class="navbar pull-left"></div>  [equivalent to float:left]
```

Comment: this is the correct answer when you want to design your navbar from right to left. specialy for RTL languages.

Answer (score 3):

Update these classes in bootstrap.css file

```
.navbar .nav {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    position: relative;
}


.navbar .brand {
    color: #777777;
    display: block;
    float: right;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 200;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
}


.navbar .nav > li {
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! There is an easier solution above.

Comment: @Reno: It will also affect all other components which uses this styles.

Comment: it will effect all .navbar elements. it depends what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The better solution is to change the value of `dir` in the `body` tag:

```
<body dir="rtl">
...
</body>
```

Comment: not wokring for navbar

Answer (score 0):

only change that... float:right to float:left

```
.navbar-toggle {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Apply float:right to ul with class as .navbar-nav

```
.navbar-nav{float:right;margin:0}.navbar-nav>li{float:right}
```